# Windows: how to set a shortcut so it open the current default browser defined in the system?

Tags: windows-7, shortcuts, default-settings

I have created a shortcut using the Windows' 7 `new shorcut` option. Now I have entered the following instrution as `emplacement`: `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" http://localhost/{path}`.

Instead of opening a specific browser -here `chrome.exe`-.  I would open the default's browser of my system, hence ensuring there would be better probability that my shortcut maintain its viability.

Maybe someone has an idea about how to do that?
thanks for any hint

Answer (score 0):

Create a shortcut that has only this as target:

```
 "http://localhost/{path}"
```

This will open the default browser on the specified URL.

Comment: thanks for answering, they say to me the target is not valid, path is a index.php file at the end, what do you think about that?

Comment: What exactly is your URL?

Comment: full path here: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" http://localhost/suitecrm

Comment: I mean the URL you use in the shortcut, which shouldn't include the browser's path.